# why android client new socket command is not working

Tags: java, android, sockets

I wrote simple android java client , main activity with socketTask and and a handler in mainactivity. and it  doesn't working .
I used debuger and found that the problem is in this line :
this.socket = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);

I also had this error massage in the studio :
An unexpected packet was received before the handshake

the server is ok and responding to any other program .
Can some one advice what is the problem . I attaching mainactivity and socket task .
thanks a lot .
main activity

````
    package com.example.app24;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    
        Button btnSend ;
        TextView tvFromServer;
        EditText etToSend;
        String strToSend,strFromServer;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    
           etToSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etToSend);
            tvFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFromServer);
            tvFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFromServer);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (v == btnSend)
            {
                strToSend = etToSend.getText().toString();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SocketTask send1 = new SocketTask(strToSend);
                        strFromServer=send1.sendReceive();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                tvFromServer.setText(strFromServer);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();
    
            }
        }
    }
    '''
    SocketTask.
    ```
    package com.example.newproj;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.util.Log;
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    public class SocketTask
    {
    
        //private final static String IP_ADDRESS = "172.19.16.179";
        private final static String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.124";
        private final static int PORT = 8821;       // HTTP port
        private final static int PACKET_SIZE = 1024;    // standard 1kb packet size
        private Socket socket;
        private String sendingStr="";
        private String receivingStr="";
        BufferedReader reader;
        public SocketTask(String str1)
        {
            this.sendingStr = str1;
    
        }
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private void send()
        {
            try {
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // outputStreamWriter creating
                writer.write(this.sendingStr);
                writer.flush();
                Log.d("Result", "sent");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
        }
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private void receive() {
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[1024];
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                reader.read(charBuffer);
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer);
                reader.close();
                receivingStr = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
        }
        public String sendReceive()
        {
            try {
                this.socket = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
                send();
                receive();
                this.socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return this.receivingStr;
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: You should tell where your server is running. You should also tell where your client app is running.

Comment: `send();
                receive();` Your send() can fail. But you still try to receive. No good. Change `private void send()` to `private boolean send()`. Or let it throw if something goes wrong.

Comment: In every catch block put `e.printStackTrace();` Then in the logcat check for exceptions. Post relevant logcat lines here.

Comment: In the last catch block also put `receivingStr=e.getMessage()`. Then the user sees it at the TextView as now the view stays empty.

Comment: INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: `// HTTP port` ? You did not tell what kind of server you run. A http server should be talked to something different...

Comment: Hi - my server is in python and he is responding to other clients . manifest ok .

Comment: Python? I asked if it was a http server. The kind of server. I did not ask for a programming language.

Comment: Hi - it's simple server to receive strings and send strings back . nothing more

Comment: some locat errors :

Comment: 2022-02-04 19:13:36.945 3628-3628/com.example.newproj D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 150939131; UID 10121; state: DISABLED
2022-02-04 19:15:46.239 3628-3821/com.example.newproj E/Exception: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.124 (port 8821) from /:: (port 36064): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2022-02-04 19:15:46.239 3628-3821/com.example.newproj W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.124 (port 8821) from /:: (port 36064): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
2022-02-04 19:15

Comment: Put the logcat lines in a nice code block in your post. Post them readable.

Comment: Hi - I just solve the problem . Thanks a lot for your help . using the e.printStackTrace() , helped me find the poroblem was at the windows firewall , I disable it and the program works . Thanks . How can I give you credit for this ?